# Maven error message regarding missing package or class

Tags: maven

I have my M2_HOME set to C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\src after reading through the mvn.bat file. It seems that I can now run the mvn command without the M2_HOME error message, but get the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64>mvn
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>
```

yes I acknowledge that I need to run it where I have the POM.xml file to get the dependency etc. information out. Also, I read the similar posts on SO regarding this error message, but it seems like hack and frig job rather than a logical solution.

I know that i would get an error message if i run `mvn` where I don't have any POM or anything, but the error message is definitely not the above.

I have downloaded maven as a zipped distribution and extracted it on my C:\ drive. My maven folder looks like the following:

```
C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\(inside there is src\bin)
C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\(Other maven folders and pom.xml)
```

I don't know if my folder setup is correct.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I just realised that I downloaded the source distribution not the binary. I downloaded the correct distribution and it worked fine (with %M2% and %M2_HOME% envvar definitions). Silly things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to point `M2_HOME` to `C:\apache-maven-3.2.5\apache-maven\src`, but rather to an actual installation directory of maven (often `C:\apache-maven-3.2.5`). What you used is a maven source code folder.

In fact you don't even need maven source code to use maven. Just download one of the binary distribution , point M2_HOME there and include M2_HOME\bin in your shell PATH

Comment: I have edited my original post. And also, there is no bin in M2_HOME. I had to change M2_HOME pointing to src folder because the bin folder is inside src. How else do I get M2_HOME correctly?

Comment: I don't think you got the correct installer package. Here's what my M2_HOME looks like http://i.imgur.com/09VJB8x.png